# iPhone - Showing overlays with UITableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: iphone, overlay, tableview

Greetings,
I have been into iOS for only 1.5 months now and I hope Im not asking a question that was already answered here. Here it is:

I have tableview that lists some duration times which each belongs to an overlay that contains coordinates with timestamps:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [dataset count]; i++)
    {   
        crumbPath = [[CrumbPath alloc] initWithCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.coordinate]; //crumbPath is my overlay

        NSDictionary *route = [dataset objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *points = [route objectForKey:@"Points"];

        for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [points count]; j++)
        {
            NSDictionary *point = [points objectAtIndex:j];

            float latitude = (float)([[point objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue]/1000000);
            float longitude = (float)([[point objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]/1000000);

            CLLocationCoordinate2D tempCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);

            [crumbPath addCoordinate:tempCoord];
        }
        [mapView addOverlay:crumbPath];
        [crumbPath release];
    }
```

As far as I have learned, I could list that durations on my tableview, what I would like to do now is, with tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method i guess, to show the overlay whose duration is tapped on the tableview. Right now, my overlays all show up on mapview, i want to show only the one that is selected.

Thanks in advance!

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer to my forgotten question.

Inside `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, i simply removed all the overlays first and added the selected one whose index i get from the tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [self.mapView removeOverlays:crumbs]; //crumbs - overlay array
     [self.mapView addOverlay:[crumbs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)removeOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay` may be used to remove the ones you don't want to show anymore.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I found my solution shortly using an array inside the didSelectRowAtIndex method.